# Laravel WhereIn() function is not array result when combine with update function

Tags: php, json, laravel, updates

I'm so confused in here, when I wanna make my data to updating to new data the result is always to be one data and the result is not array, like this :

when the query is not combine with update method :

```
public function updateData(Request $dataRequest, $myId) {
    $idUpdate = \explode(",", $myId);

    $updateQuery = RegistrationRoom::whereIn('my_id', $idUpdate)->get();

    return response()->json([
        'checked' => $updateQuery
    ]);
}
```

and for the result my json :

```
checked: [
   0: {my_id: 1, etc},
   1: {my_id: 2, etc},
   2: {my_id: 3, etc}
]
```

but when I wanna update my data with multiple row, the data is showing an error :

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["3","4","5"]' for column my_row at row 1
```

and for the data my row is `["3", "4", "5"]` :

```
public function updateData(Request $dataRequest, $myId) {
    $idUpdate = \explode(",", $myId);
    $myRow = $dataRequest->myIdRow;
    $dateNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $updateQuery = RegistrationRoom::whereIn('my_id', $idUpdate)
                   ->update([
                       'my_id_row' => $myRow,
                       'updated_at' => $dateNow
                   ]);

    return response()->json([
        'checked' => $updateQuery
    ]);
}
```

but when I remove `my_id_row` and just update field `updated_at` the result for response is last array of  `my_id`, like this :

```
public function updateData(Request $dataRequest, $myId) {
    $idUpdate = \explode(",", $myId);
    $myRow = $dataRequest->myIdRow;
    $dateNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $updateQuery = RegistrationRoom::whereIn('my_id', $idUpdate)
                   ->update([
                       'updated_at' => $dateNow
                   ]);

    return response()->json([
        'checked' => $updateQuery
    ]);

    // result json
    // checked: 3

    // for info my_id value is ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

for my registration_room table :

```
+--------------------------+------------+
+           name           +    type    +
+--------------------------+------------+
+           my_id          +     int    +
+--------------------------+------------+
+         my_id_row        +     int    +
+--------------------------+------------+
+          check_in        +     date   +
+--------------------------+------------+
+         created_at       +  timestamp +
+--------------------------+------------+
+         updated_at       +  timestamp +
+--------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: `$myRow` is an `integer` field, but you are inserting a string `["3", "4", "5"]`

Comment: so I must change that string array into the int array?

Comment: That field can accept only integer value, not array or string.

Comment: but I want to update with multiple rows alias create array data, so what is the solution for?

Comment: Your array data contains string type data, while your column has an integer value. So first make your array data into integer type then use it into whereIn, so you can update multiple data at the same time.

Comment: well, when I try to convert into integer type the error still show and for message like this : `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[3,4,5]' for column my_row at row 1`

Comment: I think you no need to insert `updated_at` column manually, because you are using Model eloquent query, this field updated by model itself when you update somethinh on the raw

Comment: yes it's already to insert that field, but error still like that, but when I'm not using that field the error is not show but my data can't update

Comment: If you update like this, it will work.  `->update(['my_id_row' => '3']);`

Comment: well if I update with a single row it's not show anything problem, what I need is how I update my data with multiple row, `update my_table set my_id_row = [3,4,5], my_table.updated_at = 2020-10-13 11:55:45 where my_id in (1, 2, 3)` and for `my_id_row` is confused value, my value from variable still array value, like not `my_id` value. nah I wanna ask how can I possible update with my multiple row data (array value)

Comment: `3` is the number of rows updated, not any 'id', `update` returns an integer of the rows affected

Answer (score 1):

**Try out this function to convert integer value**

```
public function arrayValuesToInt(&$array){
  if(is_array($array)){
    foreach($array as &$arrayPiece){
      arrayValuesToInt($arrayPiece);
    }
  }else{
    $array = intval($array);
  }
}
```

**implement this function in your parameter**

write code like in your all function `arrayValuesToInt($myId)`

```
public function updateData(Request $dataRequest, arrayValuesToInt($myId)) {
    $idUpdate = \explode(",", $myId);

    $updateQuery = RegistrationRoom::whereIn('my_id', $idUpdate)->get();

    return response()->json([
        'checked' => $updateQuery
    ]);
}
```

Comment: oke thanks for your help, I will try that code first

Comment: sorry before, when I try your code something error in my function when I implement the function in the parameter

Comment: error like this : `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)` when I try to insert the function into the parameter

Answer (score 1):

You need to update data with a loop, instead of <s>whereIn()</s> :

```
public function updateData(Request $dataRequest, $myId) {
    $idUpdate = \explode(",", $myId);
    $myRow = $dataRequest->myIdRow;
    // $dateNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    foreach($myRow as $key => $val) {

         $updateQuery = RegistrationRoom::where('my_id', $idUpdate)
                ->update([
                   'my_id_row' => $val,
             ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'checked' => $updateQuery
    ]);
}
```

Comment: SQL query inside loop (`for`, `foreach`, `while`) is not good idea. It is very slow in big array sizes!

Comment: so what should I do? I'm so stuck for this, the first step what I do changing the type of array from string to integer and it's not working, and last I use some loop in my query and it's not working too

Comment: can you update your question with `registration_rooms` table

Comment: I didn't see `my_id_row` on your table

Comment: If you want to save `["3", "4", "5"]` in your table column `my_id_row` then you need to make this field as varchar (string). But then this will be not a good database design

Comment: no I already change ["3", "4", "5"] to [3, 4, 5] but I still found the result still error